Errores con la importación de widgets en python
llevo días dándole vueltas a este error, estoy haciendo una app que ya es un poco grande, estoy actualmente creando una opción de traducción de la app en combobox, para ellos lo que elegí hacer es importar los labels en el modulo donde estoy manejando la traducción, si lo hago con un label importado desde main_structure.py me funciona perfecto, el problema viene cuando ya intento importar otro desde otro modulo diferente pues comienzo a deambular en errores de importación que no he logrado resolver. Me vendría muy bien su ayuda por favor.
Estoy utilizando babel y gettext para la traducción.
este es el código que contiene el modulo main_structure.py globalizo label_tools para que este disponible e importarlo en el modulo aplicar_traducción.
options_fm = tk.Frame(raiz)
options_fm.pack(pady=6, fill=tk.X)
options_fm.pack_propagate(False)
options_fm.configure(height=50)



def tools_page():
    from aplicar_traduccion import _, change_language
    global label_tools

    for widget in raiz.winfo_children():
        if widget != options_fm:
            widget.destroy()

    # Configura el framet para expandirse
    framet = tk.Frame(raiz, highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground='#78c0e0')
    framet.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    # Crear un Canvas dentro del Frame
    canvas = tk.Canvas(framet)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')  # Ajuste para ocupar todo el espacio del Frame

    # Agregar un Scrollbar que controla el Canvas
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(framet, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="ns")  # Ajuste para ocupar toda la altura del Frame
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", lambda e: canvas.yview_scroll(-1*(int(e.delta/120)), "units"))

    # Crear un Frame dentro del Canvas para contener las entradas y etiquetas
    frame_total = tk.Frame(canvas)
    
    # Ajustar la configuración de peso para que el Canvas se expanda correctamente
    framet.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    framet.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # Configurar el interior del Frame (Canvas)
    frame_total.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_total, anchor="nw")  # Ajustar según sea necesario


    label_tools=tk.Label(frame_total, text=_("Herramientas"), fg="#124559", font=("Poppins Medium", 60))
    label_tools.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=6)

    ml2=tk.Label(frame_total, text="Elija una opción: ", fg="#124559",
            font=("Poppins Medium", 18))
    ml2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=6)

    boton1=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Matrices", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command= pagina_matrices)
    boton1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="we", padx=(100,10), pady=30)

    boton2=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Cuadratica", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command= pagina_cuadratica)
    boton2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton3=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Integrales", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command= pagina_integrales)
    boton3.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton4=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Derivadas", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command= botonpulsado16)
    boton4.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton5=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Graficador", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command= botonpulsado17)
    boton5.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="we", padx=(100,10), pady=30)

    boton6=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Dijkstra", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command= botonpulsado18)
    boton6.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton7=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Analizador", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command= lambda:app.botonpulsado19(raiz))
    boton7.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton8=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Extractor", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command=botonpulsado20)
    boton8.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton9=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Calculadora", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command=botonpulsado21)
    boton9.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="we", padx=(100,10), pady=30)

    boton10=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Convertidor", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1,  command=lambda:app2.botonpulsado22(raiz))
    boton10.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton11=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Interpolación", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command=pagina_interpo)
    boton11.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton12=tk.Button(frame_total, text="No lineales", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command=lambda:app3.botonpulsado23(raiz))
    boton12.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton13=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Tablas de Verdad", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command=botonpulsado24)
    boton13.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="we", padx=(100,10), pady=30)

    boton14=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Regresión", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command=botonpulsado25)
    boton14.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton15=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Metodo Simplex", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command=lambda:app6.botonpulsado26(raiz))
    boton15.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton15=tk.Button(frame_total, text="Estadística", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command=botonpulsado27)
    boton15.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky="we", padx=10, pady=30)

    boton16=tk.Button(frame_total, text="ODE", width="20",font=("Poppins Medium", 15),fg='white',bg='#2a7097', bd=1, command=botonpulsado28)
    boton16.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="we", padx=(100,10), pady=30)


    change_language(event=None)


hasta ahí todo bien el problema es cuando globalizo label2 en main_screen.py para poderlo importar en aplicar traducción para poderlo configurar allí pues siempre me arroja error, este es el codigo de main_screen.py:
import tkinter as tk
from matrices.sumamatrices import raiz
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from main_structure import options_fm, tools_page




def switch(indicator_lb, page, imagen):

    for child in options_fm.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(child, tk.Label):
            child['bg'] = 'SystemButtonFace'
    indicator_lb['bg'] = '#0097e8'
    
    for widget in raiz.winfo_children():
        if widget != options_fm:
            widget.destroy()

     # Cargar imagen en cada cambio de página
    etiqueta_imagen.configure(image=imagen_tk1)  # Actualiza la imagen
    etiqueta_imagen.image = imagen  # Actualiza la referencia de la imagen
    
    page()


def home_page():
    from aplicar_traduccion import _, combo

    global imagen_tk  # Mantener una referencia global a la imagen
    global label1
    global label2
    global boton
    home_page_fm = tk.Frame(raiz)

    # Cargar imagen
    nuevo_tamano = (1300, 680)
    imagen = Image.open("C:/Users/840G3/Documents/PROGRAMACIÓN/MATH IV/multimedia/fondo_home2.png")
    imagen = imagen.resize(nuevo_tamano)
    imagen_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)

    # Mostrar imagen
    etiqueta_imagen = tk.Label(home_page_fm, image=imagen_tk)
    etiqueta_imagen.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)  # Ocupa todo el espacio del frame

    # Agregar texto
    label1 = tk.Label(home_page_fm, text=_("Calcula y Analiza \ndesde cualquier parte."), fg='#124559', bg='#eaedf2', font=("Poppins Medium", 30), highlightthickness=0)
    label1.place(x=40, y=100)  # Alinea el texto a la izquierda

    label2 = tk.Label(home_page_fm, text=_("Accede a esta herramienta que te permite \ncalcular diversas operaciones matematicas y te \npermite acceder a algunas opciones para \nel analisis de datos."), fg='#124559', bg='#eaedf2', font=("Poppins Medium", 10), highlightthickness=0)
    label2.place(x=105, y=280)  # Alinea el texto a la izquierda

    boton=tk.Button(home_page_fm, text=_("Empezar"), width="20",fg='white',bg='#2a7097', font=("Poppins Medium", 15), bd=1, command=lambda:switch(indicator_lb=product_indicator_lb,
                                                                                                                        page=tools_page, imagen=imagen_tk1))
    boton.place(x=40, y=460)

    combo()


    home_page_fm.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


def contact_page():
    contact_page_fm = tk.Frame(raiz)
    contact_page_lb = tk.Label(contact_page_fm, text='Contact Page',
                               font=('Arial', 25), fg='white')
    contact_page_lb.pack(pady=80)
    contact_page_fm.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

def about_page():
    about_page_fm = tk.Frame(raiz)
    about_page_lb = tk.Label(about_page_fm, text='About Page',
                             font=('Arial', 25), fg='#0097e8')
    about_page_lb.pack(pady=80)
    about_page_fm.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


# Cargar imagen
nuevo_tamano = (130, 40)
imagen = Image.open("C:/Users/840G3/Documents/PROGRAMACIÓN/MATH IV/multimedia/logo_mathiv.png")
imagen = imagen.resize(nuevo_tamano)
imagen_tk1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)

# Mostrar imagen
etiqueta_imagen = tk.Label(options_fm, image=imagen_tk1)
etiqueta_imagen.pack(side='right', padx=(0,32), pady=5)

home_btn = tk.Button(options_fm, text='Home', font=('Arial', 13),
                     bd=0, fg='#0897e8', activeforeground='#0097e8',
                     command=lambda: switch(indicator_lb=home_indicator_lb, page=home_page, imagen=imagen_tk1))
home_btn.place(x=0, y=10, width=125)
home_indicator_lb = tk.Label(options_fm, bg='#0097e8')
home_indicator_lb.place(x=22, y=40, width=80, height=2)

product_btn = tk.Button(options_fm, text='Products', font=('Arial', 13),
                        bd=0, fg='#0097e8', activeforeground='#0097e8',
                        command=lambda: switch(indicator_lb=product_indicator_lb,
                                              page=tools_page, imagen=imagen_tk1))
product_btn.place(x=125, y=10, width=125)
product_indicator_lb = tk.Label(options_fm)
product_indicator_lb.place(x=147, y=40, width=80, height=2)

contact_btn = tk.Button(options_fm, text='Contact', font=('Arial', 13),
                        bd=0, fg='#0097e8', activeforeground='#0097e8',
                        command=lambda: switch(indicator_lb=contact_indicator_lb,
                                               page=contact_page, imagen=imagen_tk1))
contact_btn.place(x=250, y=10, width=125)
contact_indicator_lb = tk.Label(options_fm)
contact_indicator_lb.place(x=272, y=40, width=80, height=2)

about_btn = tk.Button(options_fm, text='About', font=('Arial', 13),
                      bd=0, fg='#0897e8', activeforeground='#0097e8',
                      command=lambda: switch(indicator_lb=about_indicator_lb, page=about_page, imagen=imagen_tk1))
about_btn.place(x=375, y=10, width=125)
about_indicator_lb = tk.Label(options_fm)
about_indicator_lb.place(x=397, y=40, width=80, height=2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    home_page()
    raiz.mainloop()



este es el codigo de aplicar_traduccion.py
import gettext
from matrices.sumamatrices import raiz
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox



LOCALE_DIR = './locale'

transl = gettext.translation('messages', LOCALE_DIR, languages=['es'])
transl.install()

_ = transl.gettext  # Definir el método _ para traducción

def change_language(event):


    from main_structure import label_tools
    from main_screen import label2

    global transl  # Indicar que se está utilizando la variable global transl
    language = id_var
    transl = gettext.translation('messages', LOCALE_DIR, languages=[language.get()])
    transl.install()

    if label_tools.winfo_exists() and label_tools.winfo_ismapped():
        label_tools.configure(text=transl.gettext('Herramientas'))
    elif label2.winfo_exists() and label2.winfo_ismapped(): 
        label2.configure(text=transl.gettext("Accede a esta herramienta que te permite \ncalcular diversas operaciones matematicas y te \npermite acceder a algunas opciones para \nel analisis de datos."))
        #boton.configure(text=transl.gettext('Empezar'))
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Traducción no disponible")



def combo():
    from main_structure import options_fm
    global id_var
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.theme_use('alt')
    id_var = tk.StringVar()
    style.configure("TCombobox", fieldbackground="white", background="white")
    combo = ttk.Combobox(options_fm, style='TCombobox', width=32, textvariable=id_var)
    combo['values'] = ('es', 'en')
    combo['state'] = 'normal'
    combo.current(0)
    combo.place(x=500, y=10)
    combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", change_language)

lo he intentado hacer con labels que tengo en otros modulos y el resultado es el mismo al final siempre me aparecen errores similares a este:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\840G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1967, in call
return self.func(*args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\840G3\Documents\PROGRAMACIÓN\MATH IV\main_screen.py", line 97, in 
command=lambda: switch(indicator_lb=product_indicator_lb,
command=lambda: switch(indicator_lb=product_indicator_lb,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\840G3\Documents\PROGRAMACIÓN\MATH IV\main_screen.py", line 24, in switch
page()
File "C:\Users\840G3\Documents\PROGRAMACIÓN\MATH IV\main_structure.py", line 124, in tools_page
change_language(event=None)
File "C:\Users\840G3\Documents\PROGRAMACIÓN\MATH IV\aplicar_traduccion.py", line 20, in change_language
from main_screen import label2
ImportError: cannot import name 'label2' from 'main_screen' (C:\Users\840G3\Documents\PROGRAMACIÓN\MATH IV\main_screen.py)
PS C:\Users\840G3\Documents\PROGRAMACIÓN\MATH IV>

El identificador label2 solo existe y estará disponible a nivel global cuando home_page() sea llamada, al importar un módulo se ejecuta el código a nivel global, pero las funciones no se ejecutan. Además, el contenido bajo if __name __ == "__main__" no se ejecuta al importar el módulo (esa es una de sus principales funciones).

Sea como sea, las variables globales deben evitarse en lo posible, muy pocos casos justifican realmente su uso. Una de las razones es que contribuyen a la espaguetización del código tremendamente, llega un momento en el que es muy complicado saber dónde inicializan, dónde se usan y donde se modifican y cuando empiezan a aparecer bugs (lo cual no es raro con ellas), seguir el rastro llega a ser un dolor de cabeza... Considerara antes de que todo se complique aún más reestructurar la app, por ejemplo englobando cada página en una clase autónoma.

Pero en caso de encapsular todo en una clase, se soluciona lo de los errores de importación? Y si es así, como llamaría el label que quedó en la clase para importarlo digamos en el archivo aplicar traduccion
